# React/Redux , how to "chain" actions for http call when http call is in middleware

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am setting up a basic app to call the server for some stuff. the one catch, is I have made my server calls as a piece of middleware so other devs I work with can use it. I can make the call - however I would like to add  "loading", "success", and "error" actions to it. Before - I could easily do this by placing the calls in the action creator itself, something like this for example :

```
  //in the action creator
  export function fetchData() {
  return dispatch => {


request
  .get('/myApi')
  .end((err, res) => {
    if (err) {

      dispatch({
        type: LOADING_ERROR,
        error: err
      });
    } else {

      let myData = JSON.parse(res.text);
      dispatch({
        type: LIST_DATA,
        myData
      });
    }
  });
dispatch({
  type: LOADING_DATA
});
};
```

this worked great for me for having the loading/success/error accessible on the ui (so i can do things like show/hide a loader and such).

In this new project, I have my calls in a piece of middleware like so :

```
 //the middleware
export default (actionObject) => (store) => (next) => (action) => {

switch(action.type) {
    case actionObject.LIST:

        let constructedURL = actionObject.URL + "?query=&context=" + actionObject.context;
              request
                .get(constructedURL)
                .end((err, res) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return next(action);
                    }
                    action[options.resultAction] = res.body;
                    return next(action);
                });
        break;

    default:
        return next(action);
  }
}
```

So the `actionObject`is just an object you pass to let you set up this middleware so it will work with your own actions/reducers, but it is just matching your defined action to make the call. Now the issue is I don't know how I can get back into the loading/success/error actions from here. I have them set up in my actions and reducers but I am unsure how to execute it in this manner.

I was first looking at something like this - https://gist.github.com/iNikNik/3c1b870f63dc0de67c38#file-helpers-js-L66-L80 , however I am not sure if this is exactly what I am trying to do. I am not sure where I can tell it to fire the action `DATA_LOADING`, and then in success of the call fire either `LIST_DATA` or `LOADING_ERROR`. Could use any advice, and thank you for reading!